# Firebase not detecting css / stylesheet for web page

Tags: html, css, firebase, bootstrap-4, hosting

I am trying to host website on firebase that include two pages for now and it is working fine in my local host/ device but when i am deploying it on firebase, website index page is using the css but the other page is not including css.

I didn't get any error in the whole process of deploying it and i also have all the files and folder inside my public folder that's why i don't get it where i am wrong..

here you can access it
https://github.com/ShubhamBhardwaj2u/contest-codeground

**Problem:** when i am accessing the website index page have css but by clicking on signup tha page open without accessing css.

I have tried putting css file out of folder to the root directory but still it didn't work.

Comment: Which css file is not getting loaded?

Comment: signin.css and the bootstrap.min.css both are inside the folder named 'cssfile'

Comment: can u share the link of hosted website?

Comment: yes, here it is https://contest-b7353.web.app/

Comment: Its working right???

Comment: I can see the css is loaded and I also tried changing.

Comment: i am shocked i have been trying to solve the issue for 3 hr and then i asked here

Comment: and now it is working, i think firebase took time to proccess css or something may be. becouse when i am writing this questing it didn't showed up. sorry buddy and thanks for help

Comment: Don't worry. It happens Sometimes.